# Morris graph, edit x-axis to display date and month

Tags: scala, graph, morris.js

I want to display date and month in the x-axis in these morris graphs.
Date in the first and month in the second.
All I'm getting now is 0's and Wednesdays.
Do anybody have any good ideas as to how I can fix this?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getScript('/assets/javascripts/raphael-min.js',function(){
$.getScript('/assets/javascripts/morris.min.js',function(){

var donutData = [];
var monthLineData = [];
var yearLineData = [];

@for((activity, steps) <- morrisDonut) {
    donutData.push({label: '@activity', value: @steps});
}

@for(steps <- monthLineData) {
    if(@monthLineData.indexOf(steps) > 0) {
        monthLineData.push({ y: 
            '@{var day = Calendar.getInstance(); day.add(Calendar.DATE, -(30 - yearLineData.indexOf(steps))); day.getTime().format("EEEE");}',
            a: @steps, b: @{goals(0).steps/7} });
    } else {
        monthLineData.push({ y: '0', a: @steps, b: @{goals(0).steps/7} });
    }
}

@for(steps <- yearLineData) {
    yearLineData.push({ y: '@yearLineData.indexOf(steps)', a: @steps, b: @goals(1).steps });
}
    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'user_activity-donut',
        data: donutData
    });

    Morris.Line({
        element: 'month_step-line',
          data: monthLineData,
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
          labels: ['Steps achieved', 'Goal'],
          lineColors: ['#404080', '#000000'],
          pointSize: 0,
          parseTime: false
    });

    Morris.Line({
        element: 'year_step-line',
          data: yearLineData,
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
          labels: ['Steps achieved', 'Goal'],
          lineColors: ['#004080', '#000000'],
          pointSize: 0,
          parseTime: false
        });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's not plain javascript.... whats all this `@for` business?  Perhaps another tag would help?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Since I added morris.js the javascript part was implied. The @for parts are scala.